# Table scroll bars are not visible in Power BI Embedded Google Chrome

Tags: angular, typescript, powerbi, powerbi-embedded

In the embedded report, scroll bars for the `Table` visual are not visible in Google Chrome, but visible in Firefox.

Example:

Report in Power BI Workspace

[image]

Report in Power BI Embedded

[image]

However, I have found that if I apply the following configuration to the report, it magically fixes the problem, but I have no idea why:

```js
settings: {
    layoutType: models.LayoutType.Custom,
    customLayout: {
        pagesLayout: {
              '': { visualsLayout: { '': { } } }
        }
    }
 }
```

Basically, I want to know why this is happening and why my fix works. Thanks!

System information.

- Angular version - 11
- powerbi-client-angular version - 2.0.0
- Google Chrome version - 111.0.5563.111 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Edit: full settings and custom css that is applied to the report:

```js
settings = {
    type: 'report',
    tokenType: models.TokenType.Embed,
    embedUrl: embedParameters.embedItem.embedUrl,
    accessToken: embedParameters.embedToken.token,
    settings: {
        layoutType: models.LayoutType.Custom,
        panes: {
            pageNavigation: {
                visible: false
            },
            filters: {
                visible: false
            }
        },
        customLayout: {
            pagesLayout: {
                '': {
                    visualsLayout: {
                        '': { }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
} as IReportEmbedConfiguration;
```

```html
<powerbi-report         
    [embedConfig]="getReportConfiguration()"
    [eventHandlers]="reportEventHandlers"
    cssClassName="report-container">
</powerbi-report>
```

```css
::ng-deep .report-container {
    padding-top: 1rem;
    padding-left: 2rem;
    padding-right: 2rem;
    height: 820px;
    width: 1280px;
}
```

Comment: I tried to repro the issue, it's working fine for me. Can you please provide some more information? like sample config that you are passing to your component

Comment: @RahulRoy I've updated the description of the question, can you please check it one more time? Thanks!

Comment: [check this gist](https://gist.github.com/rad10wave/55a0fe5d506b7b7a3f0cb252f447830f)...this is what I tried, and it's working fine. Let me know if I missed anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I've found a way to solve this.

TL;DR: don't use `d-none` (`display: none`) to hide a Power BI Embedded report.

So, in my case, I had 2 reports embedded on the same page: Report 1 and Report 2, and only one report is displayed at a time. The Angular code that handles it looked something like this:

```html
<div [class.d-none]="!isReport1Displayed">
    <ng-container *ngIf="report1EmbedParameters$ | async as report1EmbedParameters">
        <powerbi-report
            #report1
            [embedConfig]="getReportConfiguration(report1EmbedParameters)"
            [eventHandlers]="report1EventHandlers"
            cssClassName="report1-container">
        </powerbi-report>
    </ng-container>
</div>

<div [class.d-none]="isReport1Displayed">
    <ng-container *ngIf="report2EmbedParameters$ | async as report2EmbedParameters">
        <powerbi-report
            #report2
            [embedConfig]="getReportConfiguration(report2EmbedParameters)"
            [eventHandlers]="report2EventHandlers"
            cssClassName="report2-container">
        </powerbi-report>
    </ng-container>
</div>
```

What happened is that both reports were loaded in parallel, but only one of them was visible. When the user clicked the button, `isReport1Displayed` switch was flipped and `d-none` (e.g. `display: none`) was applied to the second one.

For some unknown reason this caused some of the visuals on the report to render with issues - for example scroll bars not rendered at all.

The workaround for this that I've found is to apply the following CSS to hide the reports instead of `display: none`:

```css
.report-hidden {
    position: absolute;
    visibility: hidden;
    height: 0px;
    width: 0px;
    left: -9999px;
    top: -9999px;
}
```